# How can I enable express login to the Elan financial services website for Mint to access Fidelity accounts?

Tags: mint.com

When I use Mint on Android to connect to my Fidelity accounts (one of which is Fidelity Reward credit card, issued by Elan), it says that

> Fidelity needs your attention. please go to the fi website and enable
>   express login to the Elan financial services website.

Where can I enable express login?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried asking the companies involved? This is what help desks are for.

Comment: Fidelity isn't open now. They might not know because it is not their suggestion but Mint's.

Comment: Since it's a feature on their system, either they know or Mint is confused. Since it's Mint's recommendation, Mint should be able to explain it. Either way, do you really need it before Monday?

Comment: no. I may forget it after tonight.

Comment: But, whoever voted to close, support for financial software is on-topic. I personally didn't think it should be, but members spoke out and on it remains.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I was not the downvoter, but your comment sounds like you are referring to a very concrete guideline on the subject.  Can you provide a link for the guidelines for on and off topic questions?

Comment: @farnsy - Yes, I meant to return to do this. The post was [Should questions on the technical usage of a financial management tool be on-topic, or off-topic?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-questions-on-the-technical-usage-of-a-financial-management-tool-be-on-top) - I updated the FAQ [What topics can I ask about here?](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to reflect the result of that post.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the listing of all your accounts on fidelity.com (not fidelityrewards.com) and click on the credit card account (such as Fidelity Rewards Visa Signature). On that screen, in the section titled Credit Card Snapshot, there's a link called Account Services. The first time you click it, you'll get a popup requesting that you enable Express Login. Once you click I Agree, your account on fidelityrewards.com will pop up in a new window. This should enable the account for access from Mint.